# Can some explain how $2x \equiv 3 \pmod 5$ can be reduced to $x \equiv 4 \pmod 5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Given $2x \equiv 3 \pmod 5$ then

1. $2x \equiv 3 \pmod 5$
2. $3(2x) \equiv 3(3) \pmod 5$, which somehow changes to
3. $x \equiv 9 \pmod 5$

and finally even more confusing is its reduction to

$$x \equiv 4 \pmod 5$$

4??? What happened to the $9$ and $3$?

We are solving these as an equivlance relation

equivalnece realtion defined as it partitions ℤ into equivalence classes where [] denotes the equivalence class that contains integer .

Comment: In the integers modular $5$, both $9$ and $4$ are representatives of the same equivalence class i.e. they are the same exact object in this context. The same can be said for $6$ and $1$, as seen in step 2.

Comment: is there an algorithm for solving these things and reducing?

Comment: I wasn't even shown equivlance classes very well in class. Its expected we do a lot of work outside of class

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include your understanding of what an equivalence relation is and how congruencey is defined? It seems that your challenges here are from a shaky foundation in what modular arithmetic represents (especially considering your comment "I have never seen modular arithmetic" to an answer below).

Comment: yes I will attach a new definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
3(2x) \equiv 3(3) \pmod 5 \\
6x \equiv 9 \pmod 5 \\
x + 5x \equiv 9 \pmod 5 \\
x \equiv 9 \pmod 5
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This is because $5x \equiv 0 \pmod 5$.  Similarly, you have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x \equiv 9 \pmod 5 \\
x \equiv 5 + 4 \pmod 5 \\
x \equiv 4 \pmod 5
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

since $5 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$. Note, in general, $a \equiv b \pmod c \iff a - b \equiv 0 \pmod c$, i.e., $a - b = kc$ for some integer $k$. For \eqref{eq1A}, you have $5x \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ since $5x - 0 = (x)5$, and for \eqref{eq2A}, you have $5 - 0 = (1)5$.

Considering the equivalence class of $[4]$ modulo $5$, note all values, $b$, in this equivalence class are such that $b \equiv 4 \pmod 5 \iff b = 5k + 4$ for some integer $k$. In your specific case, you get $b = 9$ where $k = 1$ since $9 = 5(1) + 4$. In general, $[4] = \{\ldots, -11, -6, -1, 4, 9, 14, \ldots\}$ as $k$ goes through the integers from negative infinity to positive infinity.

Answer (score 1):

In modular arithmetic you can reduce constants any time you wish. Since $3 \times 2 = 6 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ and $3 \times 3 = 9 \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$ you see that $x \equiv1 \pmod{5}$ when you multiply both sides of the original congruence by $3$. The reason you choose to multiply by $3$ is precisely because it's the multiplicative inverse of $2$:  $3 \times 2 = 6 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$.

Comment: Im confused in your first part. showing 6 is congruent to 1 mod 5

Comment: @K.Gibson Can you please give the definition of congruence that you are using? That should be a trivial result

Comment: $6 \equiv 1(mod 5)$

Comment: @K.Gibson That is correct since $6 - 1 = 5$ is an integral multiple of $5$.

Comment: as an equivlance relation

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so in step two, you have $6x \equiv 9$ (mod 5).

Then, it also works out that $6x-5x \equiv 9-5$ (mod 5)

(Because you're just subtracting /adding multiples of $5$, it doesn't change the equivalence relation)

Comment: so why 5x? how did that come about. I have never seen modular arithmetic and I am trying to learn from videos and from my class book

Comment: we only care about the remainder (in modular arithmetic). so if 6x has a remainder of 4 when divided by 5, then 6x+5, 6x+10, and 6x-5x will also have a remainder of 4 when divided by 5

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of $2$ mod $5$ is $3$, because $3\cdot 2=6\cong1\pmod5$.  Use this fact to solve for $x$, by multiplying both sides by $2^{-1}=3$, just as you would an ordinary algebraic equation.

Get $2^{-1}\cdot2x\cong2^{-1}\cdot3\pmod5\implies x\cong3\cdot3\pmod5\implies x\cong9\pmod5\implies x\cong4\pmod5$.