# First attempt to solve a linear mod equation with one possible solution

Tags: modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

This my first concrete attempt to solve a linear mod equation with one answer. I have no idea what I am doing unless I get this right.

$$7x \equiv 6 \pmod{15}$$

$$\gcd(7,15)=1$$

So I know that there is exactly one solution

$7$ times what leaves a remainder of $6$ remainder $1$ when divided by $15$?

In this instance that number is $3$

$21x\equiv18\pmod{15}$

I can rewrite this as $x \equiv 15+6\pmod{15}$

which means $x \equiv 6\pmod{15}$

I figured I could remove the $15$ because we are in $\bmod 15$ which is our "zero"

Comment: when you typed "a remainder of $1$ when divided by $15$", did you mean "a remainder of $6$ when divided by $15$"?

Comment: yes that was a typo

Comment: you said "that number is $3$", implying that $x=3$ is a solution to $7x\equiv6\bmod15$.  I don't know why you multiplied $7x\equiv6$ by $3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve

$7x\equiv6\pmod{15}$

for unique $x \in \{0,1,2,\dots,14\}$.

You can keep adding $7$ to itself (subtracting $15$ when necessary as you go along) until you get, $\text{modulo } 15$, either

$\quad \;\;\,6\quad$ (Great - I got the answer!)
$\quad \;\;\,1\quad$ (OK, I can work with the inverse of $7$)
$\quad \,14\quad$ (Alright, $-1$ is so 'close' to $1$ I'll find the trick)

$x = 1: 7$
$x = 2: 7 + 7 = 14 = -1$

Now

$\quad 7 \times 2 \equiv -1\pmod{15} \text{ implies } 7 \times 6 \times 2 \equiv -6 \pmod{15} \text{ implies }$ 
$\quad \quad 7 \times (-6 \times 2) \equiv 6 \pmod{15} \text{ implies } x \equiv -12 \pmod{15} $

So the answer is $x \equiv 3 \pmod{15}$.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote the right thing the first time (although you did the wrong math).

Since you know $\gcd(7,15)=1$, you can realize that $7(-2)+15(1)=1$, so $$7(-2)\equiv 1\pmod{15}$$  Therefore, if you multiply both sides of $$7x\equiv6\pmod{15}$$ by $-2$, you get $$-14x\equiv-12\pmod{15}$$ or $$x\equiv 3\pmod{15}$$

Comment: how do you go from $-14x \equiv 1 mod(15)$ to $x\equiv3 mod(15)$

Comment: @K.Gibson because $-14\equiv1$ and $-12\equiv3$.

Answer (score 1):

There is not just one answer.

Here is how I would find a solution.

$7\cdot 2 \equiv -1\pmod {15}\\
7\cdot (-12)\equiv 6\pmod {15}\\
-12 \equiv 3 \pmod {15}$

But then anything of the form $3 + 15 k$ would also be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(7, 15)=1$, there's an inverse for $7\pmod{15}$.  It's $-2$, since $-2\cdot7+1\cdot15=1$.  That is, $-2\cdot7\cong1\pmod{15}$.

You can use Euclid's algorithm to find the inverse, rather than pulling a rabbit out of a hat.

Once you have the inverse, the problem resembles an algebra l exercise.  The only difference is that everything is $\pmod{15}$.

Thus $7x\cong 6\pmod{15}\implies x\cong7^{-1}\cdot6\pmod{15}\implies x\cong-2\cdot6\pmod{15}\implies x\cong-12\pmod{15}\implies x\cong3\pmod{15}$.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with the Chinese remainder theorem.

$7x\equiv6\bmod15\implies x\equiv0\bmod3$ and $2x\equiv6\bmod5$;

i.e., $x\equiv0\bmod3$ and $x\equiv3\bmod 5$.

Therefore, the solution is $x\equiv3\bmod15$.

Comment: I asked a previous question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3522743/can-some-explain-how-2x-equiv-3-pmod-5-can-be-reduced-to-x-equiv-4-pmod-5 I have no idea what I am doing yet. I haven't even seen that theorem. I am trying to comprehend how this works

Comment: @KGibson like linear polynomials as $y\equiv b\bmod m$ is like saying $y=mx+b$

Answer (score 0):

- That number is actually 13
- 18=15+3
- Yes 15 is 0, as is any multiple of it.

$$a\equiv b\pmod m\iff a=mz+b$$  with all variable integers (though z is usually ignored in a lot of cases) or equivalently
$$a\equiv b\pmod m\iff a-b=mz$$

so $$7x\equiv 6\pmod {15}\iff 7x=15z+6$$ which means $$7x=(2\cdot 7+1)z+6$$ which then follows to $$7(x-2z)=z+6$$ which is solved by $z=1$ as well as adding ( or subtracting) any multiple of 7 ( so 8,15,...) .  plugging the smallest positive value, gives $7x-14=7$ which has solution $x=3$  they actually have gaps of 7.

Anyways, back to your version (with mod 15),  $$13\cdot 7=6\cdot 15+1$$ so multiplying by 13 we have $$91x\equiv 78\pmod {15}$$ giving ( on reduction ) $$x\equiv 3\pmod {15}$$